# Data table column search issue

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery datatable with column search when I search in column filter It is disappearing. I have attached design issue screen shot here with. Below is my code

```
var table=$('#example').DataTable({
         // stateSave: true
          "ordering": false,
          "retrieve": true,
          "fixedHeader": true,
           "scrollX": true,
            // "fixedColumns": {
            //    left: 1
            //  },  

        
              scrollY: '600px',
            dom: 'lBfrtip',
            buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                text: 'Export',
                title:'Aluminum Coil Production Tracking Entries',
                className: 'btn btn-primary',
                header: true,
                exportOptions: {
                    //columns: ':visible:not(.notexport)'
                    //columns: [':visible', 16,18,19 ]
                     columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
                }
            }],
           
           
         });
        
         // Apply the search
    // table.columns().every( function () {
    //     var that = this;
 
    //     $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            
    //         if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
    //             that.search( this.value )
    //                 .draw();
    //         }
    //     } );
    // } );
             $('#example thead th').each(function() {
                const title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
                $('input', this).on('keyup change', function() {
                    if (table.column($(this).parent().index()).search() !== this.value) {
                      table
                            .column($(this).parent().index())
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                    }
                });
            });
```

[image]

Comment: Try to run it in jsfiddle?

Comment: No . I am fetching data  from database

Comment: @REVATHI you can manipulate your data then just bind datatable then we can help to you as quick as possible :D